# On minimal nonsolvable groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

This is a follow-up to this question:

[Minimal non-solvable groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865979/minimal-non-solvable-groups/3866050#3866050)

Let $G$ be a finite minimal nonsolvable group. Then by a wellknown theorem of Thompson, $Inn(S)\subseteq G\subseteq Aut(S))$, where $S$ is isomorphic to one of the following group:

(a) $L_{2}(q), q>3$,

(b) $Sz(q), q=2^{2n+1}, n\geqslant 1$,

(c) $L_{3}(3)$,

(d) $A_{7}$

(d) $M_{11}$,

(f) $U_{3}(3)$

My question,

It is clear that $G=SL_{2}(5)$ is a minimal nonsolvable group, since all of its proper subgroups are solvable. But I can't find the group $S$ for $G$ addmiting Thompson's theorem. What's wrong?

Comment: I think your list contains only the simple examples.

Comment: @Derek Holt. Could you please check the paper?

Comment: What paper? you haven't given a reference!

Comment: NONSOLVABLE FINITE GROUPS ALL OF WHOSE 
LOCAL SUBGROUPS ARE SOLVABLE1. By Thompson. section 3, Main Theorem.

Comment: So Thompson is classifying nonsolvable N-groups, which are defined to be groups in which all local subgroups are solvable, where a local subgroup is defined to be the normalizer of a nontrivial $p$-subgroup for some prime $p$. That is not the same thing as groups in which all proper subgroups are solvable. So the theorem does not apply to ${\rm SL}(2,5)$, because the whole group is a local subgroup - it is the normalizer of the centre of the group, which has order 2.

Comment: So you mean this theorem, does not help in classifying minimal nonsolvable groups. I understood it, but does there exist any similar result for the family which I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a minimal finite nonsolvable group, and let $N$ be the largest normal solvable subgroup of $G$. Then it is not difficult to see that $G/N$ must be a minimal simple group - that is, a nonabelian simple group in which every proper subgroup is solvable.

The minimal simple groups were classified by Thompson in the same paper as you are citing, and they form a subset of the groups listed above. They are listed [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_minimal_simple_groups).

Comment: @ Derek Holt. Can we say anything more about the structure of $N$. I still guess that $N$ is an elementary abelian group.

Comment: No, unfortunately $N$ can have arbitrary derived length, etc. I think its true that for any such example $G$, and any prime $p$, there is a larger example which is a nonsplit extension of an elementary abelian $p$-group by $G$.